# How to calculate angle for transform.RotateAround so the end result has a y==0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I need to solve the following puzzle:

There is a 3D cube with rotation (34,90,23) (or some other random values). I want to rotate around the local y-axis until transform.position.y == 0. In the editor I can just drag-rotate on the y axis until I see 0 as a value in the transform, but how do I do that with code? (You cannot just set y=0, because all the values change when you rotate around the local y-axis)

I am thinking about using transform.RotateAround(transform.position, transform.up, angle), but I don't know how to correctly calculate angle so that after RotateAround() the transform.rotation.y == 0.

And just to specify, I don't want to code the dragging itself, just the result. The rotation should be instant.

Can anyone write a working code for this?

Comment: This site does not provide code writing services. A request like "Can anyone write a working code for this?" is unwanted.

Comment: What is "the y axis"? The y axis of the coordinate system or the local y axis of the cube?

Comment: Thomas: I had no other way of explaining my problem. Not sure how I can ask my question without asking for code... If it can be explained by other means, that is totally OK by me.

By Y-axis I mean transform.up

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is an "animation" that will affect the `transform.localEulerAngles.y` value. To achieve this I'd recommend using a coroutine (you can find Unity tutorial [here](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines)).

It would look like this:

```
private IEnumerator RotateAroundY(float rotationTime)
{
    float timer = 0.0f;
    Vector3 startLocalEulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles;
    Vector3 deltaLocalEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, Mathf.DeltaAngle(startLocalEulerAngles.y, 0.0f), 0.0f);

    while (timer < rotationTime)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localEulerAngles = startLocalEulerAngles + deltaLocalEulerAngles * (timer / rotationTime);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    transform.localEulerAngles = startLocalEulerAngles + deltaLocalEulerAngles;
}
```

And you can call it using `StartCoroutine(RotateAroundY(4.0f));`.

If you're getting into Unity I highly recommend you to familiarize with coroutines :)

**EDIT :**
Sorry about not noticing you didn't needed an animation: if you simply want to rotate around the local `transform.up` vector, you can change the `transform.localEulerAngles.y` value.

You can do it this way `transform.localEulerAngles.y = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, 0.0f, transform.localEulerAngles.z);`

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: No, I don't want an animation. As I said: "And just to specify, I don't want to code the dragging itself, just the result. The rotation should be instant."

Comment: Sorry about not noticing the _"And just to specify, I don't want to code the dragging itself, just the result. The rotation should be instant."_ sentence: I only took the _"I want to rotate around the local y-axis until transform.position.y == 0."_ sentence into account and I hope you agree it feels like you needed an animation... Anyway rotating around local `transform.up` equals changing `transform.localEulerAngles.y` value so I guess you just have to write `transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, 0.0f, transform.localEulerAngles.z);`